# Option menu in a tabbed activity in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to create a fragmented activity with 2 fragments in android studio with an options menu with item as `showAsAction:never`. I have tried everything and have overridden `onOptionsItemSelected` and `onCreateOptionsMenu` in both fragments and `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`. After that i tried to change the theme of my activity from `NoActionBar` to something else but every theme i tried did not work.

Here's some of my code on fragments:

```java
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.about){
            //do something
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

...and there is my manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ubbscraper">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme1">
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".AddSubjectsActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddSubjectsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme1"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The theme that i am trying to change is in the MainActivity.
Here is the menu code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Despre"/>
</menu>
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

style.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.about:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

**EDIT**

I edited the code and the app name is shown only once but the menu isn't shown

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Taops.jpg)

Comment: I'm confused, please explain what are you trying to achieve, exactly.

Comment: I don't want the "UbbScraper" twice. I want that options menu just next to the app name not the app name on top of the fragments and in the toolbar.

Comment: @radu2147 post up your style.xml and the main actvity xml (where your fragments lies code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**add this your style.xml:**

```
 <style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**then add apptheme1 in manifest:-**

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme1">
```

For 3 dots :
You must include toolbar inside appbarlayout your layout of Mainactivity
Then add `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` on oncreate of Mainactivity

Comment: then just apply   android:theme="@style/AppTheme1" under <actvity>

Comment: try removing this ==>         setHasOptionsMenu(true);

Comment: You are having onCreateOptionsMenu() on fragment and Mainactivity... Try removing one onCreateOptionsMenu on fragment

Comment: Tried it 2 times with only one onCreateOptionsMenu every time, did not show the menu

Comment: See my edit... Keep oncreateoptionmenu in Mainactivity